# Core Plot: How to scale to fit a plot while scaling axes equally?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, core-plot

I'm using Core Plot to graph linear equations. I have two data points; the X and Y intercept of the line.
I want to scale the the plot area to fit the plot in view.

I tried using

```
[plotspace scaleToFitPlots: [NSArray arrayWithObject:mainPlot]];
```

which worked, except that the axes were scaled independently:

[image]

The X axis is stretched relative to the Y axis. So that the slope of the line is shown accurately, it is important that both axes be scaled together.

**How can I scale a plot area to fit a plot while maintaining an equal relationship between axes?**

To be clear, the range of the axes can vary, but the physical amount of onscreen space between 0 and 1 needs to be the same on both axes.

Answer (score 0):

After calling `-scaleToFitPlots:`, inspect the resulting plot ranges and adjust them as needed to achieve the effect you want. Compare the length of each range to the corresponding dimension of the plot area `bounds` (compute the ratio between the length and bounds size), determine if one ratio is larger than the other, and adjust the ranges as needed so the ratios match.